# python keyboard wont stop once key is pressed

Tags: python, keyboard

I have an endless loop in MAIN and ive looked at it so many times.

```
def click(x,y):
   win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
   win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
   time.sleep(0.05)
   win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

def click_x_box(Box_x_axis, X_axis, Y_Axis_top, Y_Axis_bottom):
   #[Check if pixel is RED from top]
   while pyautogui.pixel(X_axis, Y_Axis_top)[0] == 255 and pyautogui.pixel(X_axis, Y_Axis_top)[1] != 255:
       # click function has no loops
       click(Box_x_axis, Y_Axis_top)
       Y_Axis_top += 19
   print("finished top-down loop")

   #[Check if pixel is RED from bottom]
   while pyautogui.pixel(X_axis, Y_Axis_bottom)[0] == 255 and pyautogui.pixel(X_axis, Y_Axis_bottom)[1] != 255:
       click(Box_x_axis, Y_Axis_bottom)
       Y_Axis_bottom -= 19
   print("finished bottom-up loop")
```

After I press 'q' once the "keyboard.is_pressed" line will keep re-going through, I dont know why it keeps getting through if 'q' is not being held down?

```
def main():
   # Continue unticking boxes while 'q' is held
   print("Hold 'q' to start clearing out the page of red")
   while True:
       if keyboard.is_pressed("q") == True:
           print("q is pressed")
           click_x_box(Box_x_axis, X_axis, Y_Axis_top, Y_Axis_bottom)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

***EDIT***
Ive figured out that when for whatever reason the click function is still engaging despite there being no 255,0,0 (red) on screen...

[image]

Comment: I should mention ive taken out the "click_x_box" method and it works just fine. BUT it will only work if i hold 'q' in the IDLE run screen, if i click off idle and just onto my desktop then while holding 'q' nothing will happen.

Comment: when it endlessly loops do you see "q  is pressed" come up over and over and over?  If not then the problem is in your click_x_box function.

Comment: yeh i do see "q is pressed" thats the problem, i dont know how theres a loop here at all.

Comment: Ive figured out, that holding 'q' is causing an endless loop, but if i do the MAIN function without click_x_box holding 'q' is fine.